# delivery optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithms

The problem is best illustrated with an example. Consider a trading system in which `A` sells to `B` who sells to `C`.

> A -> B -> C

At some point in the future `A` needs to *deliver* the sold goods to `B` who in turn needs to deliver to `C`.

From this trivial example it can be seen that `A` could deliver directly to `C` without involving `B` and reducing the number of deliveries:

> A -> <s>B -></s> C

One constraint is that `A` might not be able to deliver to `C` (predefined rules) and in that case the original pathway (`A->B->C`) would be used

What type of problem is this mathematically? What might I use to assist solving problems of this nature? The inputs to the algorithm would be:

1) A list of all the trades (`A` sells 99 widgets to `B`, `A` sells 31 widgets to `C` etc)

2) A matrix detailing whether a seller can deliver to any given buyer (A can deliver to B,C,D but not E or F)

Here is another example:

`A -> B -> C`   (`A` sells to `B` who sells to `C`)

`D -> E -> F`   (`D` sells to `E` who sells to `F`)

**Constraint**: `A` cannot deliver to `C`

**Required**:

1) `A` and `D` have to deliver

2) `C` and `F` have to receive

**Answer**: `A` delivers to `F`; `D` delivers to `C`  (2 deliveries)

whereas

**Unoptimized**: `A` delivers to `B`; `B` delivers to `C`;`D` delivers to `E`;`E` delivers to `F`  (4 deliveries)

Comment: This seems like an all-pairs shortest path problem with constraints (see: [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)). The idea of shortcut `A->B->C` to just `A->C` is just applying the triangle inequality (e.g. the shortest delivery path between to persons is a direct delivery if possible).

Comment: @Evil I dont understand (so please be nice) - A can deliver to C and F however D *must* also make a delivery as they have a net position (i.e. they sold something and must deliver it to *someone*) - unlike say `B` who has no *net* position (they bought and then sold equal amounts)

Comment: `are there always the same number of senders and receivers` <-- no there could be a case where there is one seller who sells to 10 different buyers. in this (simple) case 10 deliveries would be required